# render a component in full screen view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to render a component in full screen view. Let us suppose the component is already mounted and it's available in the DOM.

```
// container for full screen view
<div>{anyComponent}</div>
```

Is there any way to view the component in full screen? rather than importing again & pass it to full screen view.

Answer (score 1):

By making use of `.requestFullscreen()`.

Here is an example:

```js
<div onclick="event.target.requestFullscreen()">click me!</div>
```

Of course, you don't *need* to use `onclick`

PS: btw, please note that default background-color in fullscreen is not the same as not in fullscreen, so you may need to account for this in your styling.